Prevent options from passing to packages?
My MWE:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{alice.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplClass{alice} {2024/12/22} {0.9} {A class for Alice.}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[alice]
  { \ClassWarning{alice}{Unknown~option~‘\CurrentOption’~ignored} }
\ProcessKeyOptions[alice]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{bob}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bob.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage {bob} {2024/12/22} {1.0} {Commands for Bob.}
\DeclareKeys [bob]
  {
    checkbox .store = \checkbox
  }
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[bob]
  { \ClassWarning{bob}{Unknown~option~‘\CurrentOption’~ignored} }
\SetKeys [bob] { checkbox = unchecked }
\ProcessKeyOptions [bob]

\tl_log:e { Checkbox:~\checkbox }

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[checkbox = {checked!}]{alice}

\begin{document}
This is my checkbox: \checkbox
\end{document}

When I process this, the "checkbox" option, which is not allowed in the alice class, is propagated on to the bob package, so that in the log file I see
...
Document Class: alice 2024/12/22 v0.9 A class for Alice.
Class alice Warning: Unknown option ‘checkbox = {checked!}’ ignored on input line 11.
...
Package: bob 2024/12/22 v1.0 Commands for Bob.
> Checkbox: checked!.

Naively, I assumed that "handling" an unknown key meant removing it from further processing. Apparently, this is not the case.
My goal is to make sure that a user of alice cannot inadvertently break the behavior by specifying options that aren't supported by the class itself. Presumably, one approach would be to explicitly process any options that might be used by a package, but that's suboptimal.
Is there a simple way to prevent options from passing to packages with explicitly listing in the class file every single option a package might use? Maybe add \DeclareUnknownKeyHandler* which removes keys as they are handled?

You mean no option should be forwarded to any package there is? You could empty the global option list, but this would break established LaTeX syntax. For instance one is advised to set the language one uses as a global option.

@Skillmon I want the ability to control what options are passed along.

Well, with \DeclareUnknownKeyHandler you handle every key, and if you want to remove that from the list of keys to be considered by packages it effectively means remove every key from the list of keys for packages. Or am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
